# iOS XMPP chat through HTTP proxy

Tags: ios, http, proxy, xmpp

I have an iPhone application which works with 2 services:

1. work with REST service over http - use AFNetworking
2. have XMPP chat over TCP - use XMPPFramework https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

My iPhone uses corporate network with proxy, so I set HTTP proxy in Settings  http://qblx.co/1eJ9TwI

With this proxy settings all requests to REST service go through this proxy.
But, my application connects direct to Chat server, without proxy.

How to make Chat works through proxy?
As I can see, XMPPFramework uses GCDAsyncSocket as a transport https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

Do you have any suggestions how to setup Chat through proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XMPP by default uses plain **TCP** socket connection, which is not able to route via **HTTP** proxy. You can:

- if your proxy supports HTTPS/Tunneling, try to use 443 port for your XMPP service, or forward 443 port to default XMPP service port(5222) on your router.
- if your proxy supports SOCKS, try to use [ProxyKit](https://github.com/chrisballinger/ProxyKit), but it may need to modify XMPPFramework code
- You can try to use XMPP with HTTP or Websocket transport, but XMPPFramework did not support it and you may need to find/write different library

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer. Regarding 2nd one - is it possible to have a proxy which supports both HTTP and SOCKS? I think it's the best solution here. Can you also provide a bit more info regarding 1st one - what I should do on each side?

Comment: hey @vitalster can i check both thing with user registration HTTPS url link and XMPP server login(setupStream of code)...because i want to chat direct with other users of my contact...is it possible?...can you give some hint or suggestion for it ?