# Connect to XMPP over websocket on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, websocket, xmpp, xmppframework

I need to connect to an XMPP server over websocket on iOS (`ws://chat.something.com:1234/websocket`). I am using `XMPPFramework`, but I cannot find a way to make it connect over websocket.

I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23114564/310121 that suggests that `XMPPFramework` doesn't support this. As far as I can tell, that seems to be true.

So is there any way to connect to an XMPP server over websocket on iOS without writing your own library or extending `XMPPFramework` (or some alternative library) to support this?

Comment: Have you checked this: https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream?

Answer (score 4):

`XMPPFramework` uses TCP sockets. It has not provided any API's or provision for `websockets`.
In order to connect with your server using `websockets`, you will have to alter `XMPP Library's` code.
I had the same issue, and i resolved it by replacing `XMPPStream` class of `XMPPFramework` (that deals with the actual TCP socket connection) with custom stream class, and used `SocketRocket` library to connect over `websocket` with my server.